# Invalid argument for foreach associative array loop

Tags: wordpress, foreach

I've got an invalid argument supplied for my last associative array foreach loop. I am looping through different email addresses and creating an array. Am I doing something wrong? Should I create a null array?

Cheers!

```
    global $wpdb, $wpsc_variations;

    $stock_table = $wpdb->prefix . 'postmeta';
    $posts_table = $wpdb->prefix . 'posts';

    $q = 'SELECT DISTINCT post_id FROM ' . $stock_table . ' WHERE meta_key=\'' . NOTIFY_META . '\' AND meta_value=1';
    $q_assoc_arr = $wpdb->get_results($q, ARRAY_A);

    foreach($q_assoc_arr as $row) {

        $product_id = $row['post_id'];

        $product_data = get_post_custom( $product_id );
        $product_data['meta'] = maybe_unserialize( $product_data );
        foreach ( $product_data['meta'] as $meta_key => $meta_value ) {
            $product_data['meta'][$meta_key] = $meta_value[0];
        }

        if ($product_data['meta']['_wpsc_stock'] > 0) {

            foreach (get_post_meta($product_id, NOTIFY_EMAILS_META, true) as $k=>$v) {

                $emails[] = $v;

            }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your third `foreach` relies on the output of [get_post_meta](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_meta), but you're passing **true** as the 3rd parameter. This tells `get_post_meta` to return a single value as a **string**, not an **array**.

`foreach` expects an array to iterate over. :)

**Note:** This part will fail for certain, but your other instances of `foreach` may also fail if an array is not passed.

Comment: Thanks spencer, any suggestions on how I should format get_post_meta then?

Comment: If there are multiple custom fields named `NOTIFY_EMAILS_META`, then just pass `false` as the 3rd parameter to `get_post_meta` or simply leave the parameter off altogether and it will default to `false`.